# Page content sent from XML RPC is corrupted

Tags: xml-rpc

I am using python-wordpress-xmlrpc to edit a page to wordpress, I generate some HTML and I am sending it to wordpress. The content is a piece of valid html code, it consists of regular html tags and some text. However when I browse to the page in Wordpress dashboard, the page content looks like:

```
h2My Product C++/h2

div style=”border: 2px solid #ECECEC;-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #888;”
p align=”justify”bFDM/b (bx) is something nice
```

As you see `<h2>` becomes `h2>`, `<div>` has become `div>`.

The HTML on the Python side looks OK, so I am guessing that I am not using the XML RPC correctly. Any ideas where/why this sort of corruption would occur?

Comment: We need to see your code that you are using to send the request etc. Bear in mind the XML part, which means you have to escape the < etc, that could be problem, but need to see code.

Answer (score 0):

turns out to be a libxml2 bug due to an old version on our server. Luckily a fix exits: the LibXML2-fix plugin.